# How to reattach branches in git after interactive rebase

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase

I have a relatively simple Git history, mostly a line with several tags alongside it. However, there is four branches along the road, where several experimental changes were made.

So, the tree look(ed) like this:

`HEAD
 |
 D
 |
...
 |
 C-C1-C2-<branch1-head>
 |
...
 |
 B-B1-<branch2-head>
 |
...
 |
 A-<some-tag>
 |
...`

It's a completely local repository, so there is no complications like remote repos.

Recently I have made a fixup commit which is related to the commit really, really deep down the history (let's say commit `A` in the diagram). I then ran the

`git rebase -i A~1`

And squashed the fixup commit to the commit A. Git happily re-run all the 75 commits after that, but then the history became completely wrong. All the commits after the changed `A` commit became duplicated into separate line of commits, and all branches left where they were, attached to original line of commits. So, I now have HEAD pointing to the clone of the original line of commits, but I certainly don't want to have this duplication in the repo.

- What I don't understand in the interactive rebase so it lead to this problem?
- How can I now re-attach the branches to the new line of commits so garbage collector will be able to purge the old one? Is there other option than manually correct the commit objects to make them point to new parent commits?

Comment: You can't change history, you can only add new history.  Rebase adds new history by applying detected diffs onto the new base, and makes the reference you gave it refer to the tip of the new history rather than the old.  Either finish your history rewrite by also rebasing your branches onto the commits corresponding to their branch bases in the new history, or switch your master ref back to its original commit and apply your fixup to existing history.

Comment: @jthill Why the comment and not the answer? Also, do I understand correctly that rebase by itself does exactly what I want to achieve: grab a whole branch and "reattach" it to some another commit specified? And the history rewrite is a side effect of using it to "reattach" the branch to some commit inside itself? Maybe *that* is what I did not understand in rebasing.

Comment: You're thinking in abstractions.  Git is concrete.  Git refs (branches and tags -- and anything else you care to cook up) are nothing more than labels you can hang on the history in your repo.  Focus on the commits. Use refnames only as a way to get to them.  Rebase does what you've seen it do: it makes new commits and rehangs the ref you gave it.  The history rewrite isn't a side effect or implementation artifact, it's what rebase does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jthill already gave you the answer [as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103906/how-to-reattach-branches-in-git-after-interactive-rebase#comment39069410_25103906): `git rebase` (whether interactive or not) simply *copies* commits to a *new* chain, then moves the (single) branch label to the new chain:

```
..- * - A - ... - B - ... - C - ... - D   <-- branch
                    \         \
                     ...       ...        [other branches]
```

becomes:

```
        A'- ... - B'- ... - C'- ... - D'  <-- branch
      /
..- * - A - ... - B - ... - C - ... - D
                    \         \
                     ...       ...      [other branches]
```

where the `'`-suffixed varieties are the copies that `git rebase` makes (it *must* make these due to git's internal design, which "leaks out" since git's abstractions are not all that abstract).

The other branches are of course still attached to the original, unmodified commits.

To make those other branches be re-based onto the new commits, you have to `git rebase` each one individually (making yet more copies, this time of just the commits currently reachable only via the other branches)—*or*, instead of rebasing `branch` at all, you could use git's `filter-branch` command, which is sort of like `git rebase` on steroids.<sup>1</sup>

What `git filter-branch` does is very much like what `rebase` does: it copies commits, allowing you to slip changes in along the way (just before finalizing each new copy).  Then, also like `rebase`, it moves labels (branches at least, and optionally tags as well, though you must give it a tag name filter for this to happen).  Besides the bewildering array of filter options, though, the other thing that `git filter-branch` does that `git rebase` doesn't is that it can move *many* labels, rather than just one branch-label.

The drawback here is that `git filter-branch` is (or can be) *very* hard to use.  You need to understand, in a lot of detail, what git is doing with each commit.  By limiting the problem-set, `git rebase`—which is already not the easiest command for most users—avoids this.

Thus, you're probably best-off using `git rebase` to move your `branch1` (`C`-based chain) and `branch2` (`B`-based chain) onto `C'` and `B'` respectively, if you really want to rewrite your commit history this way.  To do that:

```
# Figure out which commit is original commit `C` and
# what its new copy `C'` is; put these into the commands
# below.

C=$(git merge-base branch1 'branch@{yesterday}')
git show $C               # make sure you have the right one
git log --oneline branch  # find the SHA-1 for C'
C1=badcafe                # or whatever its SHA-1 is
```

Incidentally, the `'branch@{yesterday}'` notation is a trick for looking in the reflog to see where `branch` ended yesterday (presumably this finds commit `D` in the drawing), as opposed to where `branch` ends today (the tip of `branch` is now commit `D'`, which is not what you need here).  If you know the raw SHA-1 of original commit `D`, or can find it some other way (such as by running `git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD`), that's another way to get it.

You'll have to find the right SHA-1 for `C1` manually.  The `git log --oneline` above will show you the short messages for each of the copied commits; you can compare them to the output from `git show $C`.  If you have multiple candidates (because there are several short-logs that all just say "fix a bug" for instance), you may need to use more `git show` commands to find `C1`.  But I'll assume you *can* find the copy, and have set `C1`:

```
# now that we have the IDs of C ($C) and C' ($C1), use
#    git rebase --onto
# to re-base branch1 (the chain coming off original C)
# onto commit $C1, and then move label "branch1"
git rebase --onto $C1 $C branch1
```

Now we just repeat this process for the `B` chain that you are calling `branch2`:

```
B=$(git merge-base branch2 'branch@{yesterday}')
git show $B
git log --oneline branch
B1=d0gf00d                # or whatever the correct copy SHA-1 is
git rebase --onto $B1 $B branch2
```

If the fix-up you applied to commit `A` (resulting in new commit `A'`) interferes with any of the changes you have in `branch2` or `branch1`, these `git rebase`s will pause, let you recover manually, and then let you use `git rebase --continue` to finish the changes.

(If you were to attempt to do this all with `git filter-branch`, you would, in effect, have to provide a scripted method of handling any such conflicts.  That's one of the things that makes doing this with `git filter-branch` so difficult.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The thing I think is most amusing about this is that people already consider `git rebase` to be pretty steroidal.  The `rebase` command basically runs an automated series of `git cherry-pick`s.

Comment: I can only add to this thorough and insightful answer that I used GUI viewer for Git history to get the correct hashes for commits I need, and the moving branches with further `git rebase` commands did exactly what I needed. Explanations about how to make it completely in console mode are priceless, though.

I think I just got stuck out of fear that further `git rebase` commands will convolute my commit history even more. :)